# Mysql insert current result and then insert new result

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have an ajax live table edit to change the price of my current product.  What I want to do is insert the price before I change it and then insert the updated price.  The reason being is because I want to show the change in the updated price.  Example: current price is $54.00 and I change it to $57.00.  I need to keep a log of price change throughout the day and show the price change of $3.00.  How would I go about inserting the old price while the updated price gets inserted also.  Thanks.

Comment: just make a table and insert a new record init whenever there is a change and use foreign key to track the price record id..i hope that will give you an idea and also have two columns one updated and one old

Comment: Why don’t you just keep 2 prices in the database instead of one? Otherwise could you just add a new "delta" field in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you make your price table like this

```
table price
-----------
id          unsigned integer autoincrement primary key
article_id  integer /*link to articletable*/
valid_from  date
valid_until date
amount      decimal(10,2) /*always use decimal for money*/
```

Then you can insert your new price using the following 4 queries.

```
/*hide changes from the rest of the world until we are done*/
START TRANSACTION

/*invalidate the latest existing price in the price table*/
UPDATE price 
SET valid_until = DATESUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
WHERE article_id = '100' ORDER BY valid_until DESC LIMIT 1
/*the order by selects the latest item, the limit does only 1 update*/

/*insert the new price*/
INSERT INTO PRICE (article_id, valid_from, valid_until, amount) 
VALUES ('100', CURDATE(), DATEADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 100 YEAR), '99.95')

/*show changes to the rest of the world*/
COMMIT
```

You need the transaction or you risk the price table being out of sync. Set the tabletype to `InnoDB` on the price table. 
Al your other tables can be `MyISAM`, just make sure the `price` table is `InnoDB`.

You can now select prices by using:

```
SELECT article.name
  ,price.amount as price_per_item
  ,purchase.qty as number_of_items
  ,price.amount * purchase.qty as amount 
FROM purchase
INNER JOIN article ON (article.id = purchase.article_id)
INNER JOIN price ON (price.article_id = purchase.article_id) 
  AND (purchase.transactiondate BETWEEN price.valid_from and price.valid_until)
WHERE purchase.id = '458'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can maintain to different fields for the two. Like old_value and new_value. At the end of the day you can tally the values and print the difference.